# How to reject the entire input CSV file when any row failed validation rule

Tags: talend

I have an input CSV file and if one or more rows failed during validation check, then I want to move the input CSV file from InProcess folder to Failed folder and none of the rows should be processed.

I've created a job but the above scenario doesn't seem to work. Can you please help?

tFileInputDelimited --> tSchemaValidationCheck --> tFileCopy

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to output the reject data into the same file and then run the "tFileCopy_1" in the same branch.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is not very elegant , but it should work.

You want to know how many lines have been rejected : if it is 0 , you can continue with the main task. If it is more than 0, you'll have to stop and copy your input file.

Unfortunately, tSchemaCompliance does not have a global variable like  `NB_LINES_REJECTED` , as you can have with DBOutput components for example.

Here, the reject flow goes to a tLogRow : in my IF links , I can then test how many lines appear in this tLogRow (  `((Integer)globalMap.get("tLogRow_1_NB_LINE"))>0`) : if it is 0 , you can stop and copy the input file.

Otherwise, you'll have to read your input file again.

Here, the tJava component is only used to output IF links. 
[image]